# How do I split a vector and minimize absolute error efficiently?

Tags: median, change-point

I have a vector $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to find a computationally efficient way to find a split point $k$, such that:

$\sum_1^k |y_i-\theta_1|+\sum_{k+1}^n |y_i-\theta_2|$ is minimised. The $\theta$ values are the median of the set they are in.

I can easily find such a point iterating amongst all possible $k$ values, but I assume there is a faster way to do it and a theoretical explanation (in the end this is just a simple case of change point detection).

I post a code sample that performs the task using a for loop in R. I do not care about the programming language for the answer, I would prefer to understand how it is done faster.

```
set.seed(1)
n<-20L
y<-rnorm(n)
besterror<-Inf
for(i in 1:(n-1L)){
  y1<-y[1:i]
  y2<-y[((i+1L):n)]
  theta1<-median(y1)
  theta2<-median(y2)
  error<-sum(abs(y1-theta1))+sum(abs(y2-theta2))
  if(error<besterror){
    k<-i
    besterror<-error
  }

}
print(paste("Best split at",k,"absolute error",besterror))
```

Comment: I believe that by using a suitably labeled [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) you could scan the vector at a cost of $O(\log(i)+\log(n-i))$ at position $i$, yielding a $O(n\log(n))$ algorithm.  It's hard to see how such asymptotic performance could be improved on--but note that finding the median of $n$ values does not actually require sorting and can be done in $O(n)$ time, which would not preclude the possibility of yet a better algorithm.

Comment: You don't say it but this sounds like an LDA (latent dirichlet allocation) partitioning of the simplex into *k* groups where *k* is minimized with the maximum possible revealed structure. For a good overview of this, see David Blei's video tutorial on LDA here ... http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_blei_tm/  Blei recommends Pritchard's approach to partitioning *k* based on population genetics here ... http://web.stanford.edu/group/pritchardlab/home.html  A good intro to Pritchard's approach is here ... http://pbgworks.org/sites/pbgworks.org/files/Tutorial%20of%20STRUCTURE%20software.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done in $O(n)$ time if $y$ is sorted. In my pseudo-R it would look something like

```
P = prefix_sums(y) // O(n)
S = suffix_sums(y) // O(n)
min_idx = -1
min_sum = Inf
low_idx, high_idx = 0, 0
low_val, high_val = 0, 0
for (i in 1:length(y)) {
    low_idx, low_val = med_low(y, i) // get median index and value in lower part
                                     // O(1) since y - sorted
    high_idx, high_val = med_high(y, i) // O(1)
    sum_low = low_idx * low_val - P[low_idx] 
            + (P[i] - P[low_idx - 1]) - (i - low_idx) * low_val 
    sum_high = (high_idx - i - 1) * high_val - (S[i + 1] - S[high_idx])
             + S[high_idx] - (n - high_idx + 1) * high_val
    if (sum_low + sum_high < min_sum)
        // update ...
}
```

Basically the idea is that we can calculate the two sums in constant time if we precomputed all partial prefix and suffix sums of vector $y$. Also, finding median in sorted vector is also $O(1)$

Comment: The assumption that $y$ is sorted is an extremely special case!  (Only $2/n!$ out of all such vectors are sorted.  The example given in the question is unlikely to be sorted.)  If by "is sorted" you mean *if we first sort $y$*, then (1) that's a $O(n\log(n))$ operation and (2) you would lose the information about the original order.  Even if you retained that information, how would you use it? Finally, what exactly do you mean by "prefix" and "suffix" sums? Are you ignoring the absolute values?

Comment: @whuber Well isn't it assumed in OP question?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "is sorted"!  The data given in the question are not sorted by value, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @whuber Well i must've misunderstood "ordered vector" as "sorted vector", so what does even "ordered vector" mean? In couple years time haven't seen someone using this term

Comment: Now that you call attention to it, I agree that "ordered vector" is confusing.  However, it is clear in the code in the question that $y$ is not ordered--it's just an array created as `y <- rnorm(n)`. I am curious, though: it's not evident what your algorithm is doing, because it seems not to handle the absolute values.

Comment: @whuber It does handle them by splitting each sum into summing over values greater than median and lower

Comment: But since the two medians are changing dynamically as you scan, it would seem you also have to do some additional work that might be proportional to $O(i)+O(n-i)$ effort at step $i$, leading to a $O(n^2)$ algorithm.

Comment: If you assume sorted vector than finding median is simply middle element, or sum of two middle ones, so its $O(1)$ anyway, I omitted this part, it's ugly

Comment: I erased ordered from the question because it was deceiving. I was looking for something like the self-balancing binary search tree proposed by whuber (I will try to write the code for it and post it as an answer). That said, I was thinking about performing a bootstrapping on my vector, so your approach might be very useful for me too.

Comment: @JonNagra Balanced trees are one possibility, it seems that assymptotically the same, but faster would be keeping one max-heap and min-heap that would yield median in constant time, and also summing would be possible in constant time, but still inserting new element would be $O(logn)$.

Answer (score 1):

The changepoint.np R package does this in O(n) time using a range of quantiles.

```
library(changepoint.np)
set.seed(1)
n<-20L
y<-rnorm(n)
out<-cpt.np(y)
cpts(out)
```

This uses the defaults and identifies that there are no changes in the data.  If you want to know which location is the most likely for a changepoint then you can use the CROPS penalty:

```
out1<-cpt.np(y,penalty="CROPS",pen.value=c(3,7))
cpts.full(out1)
```

The CROPS penalty gives you all segmentations within a range of penalties, using `cpts.full` we can see all the segmentations with a penalty between 3 and 7 in the above.  It gives from no changepoints at a penalty of 7 to eight changes for a penalty of 3 and all in between.

You can set nquantiles=1 but i'm not sure what quantile that would calculate, you would need to read the original paper here (open access):
[PAPER](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-016-9687-5)

It isn't quite the answer to the question as it isn't a single changepoint, but it is a more general solution, potentially multiple changes and different quantiles, with a faster O(n) computational time than those listed already.

Comment: I read the article and to my understanding the package deals with a mse error. I am trying to use a mae error as my time series have several outliers.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the MAE part.  I think you should still try the package as the use of the EDF with a small number of quantiles reduces the effect of outliers.